# Rails invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All i am doing is `rails s` from the code downloaded from a server, which is running without a problem, but it is stubborn to go past this error

```
rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:36:in `[]': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:36:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

any little help would be a life saving tip for me, banging my head for couple of days with in-numerous installations and configurations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could that be an error reading config.ru?

Answer (score 0):

Use `gem 'rack-utf8_sanitizer'` or `gem "handle_invalid_percent_encoding_requests"` in your gemfile and run `bundle`.

Comment: this link should help you http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2014/03/rack-argument-error-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8/

Comment: thanks, as i said i tried those for past two days whichever search engine gives me, is there any way i could find out which file causes this? Thanks for your time